# Why is not common the use of Private properties/methods in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, accessor

First of all let me tell you that I just started playing around with Swift and haven't really seen a lot of code written in it but all of the tutorials I have seen they don't use private as in some other languages and as I understand Swift has three access controls, `Private`, `Public` and `Internal`, with `Internal` being the default.

I'm a little confused and despite the fact that I don't have a lot of programming experience in general but my understanding was that in a program you make everything private and only make public the properties and methods that you want to expose to other classes.

From Apple Docs

> In addition to offering various levels of access control, Swift
>   reduces the need to specify explicit access control levels by
>   providing default access levels for typical scenarios. ***Indeed, if you
>   are writing a single-target app, you may not need to specify explicit
>   access control levels at all.***

To me by leaving every property/method as the default (`Internal`) you are basically giving access to other classes to their values, correct?

Why is that in Swift/Cocoa you rarely see the use of the `Private` accessor for properties that you don't want other parts of your program to have access?

Can someone be so kind and explain the concept accessors in general and why is Swift designed this way, or even better correct me if I'm wrong in the assumption I'm making above, again I don't have to much experience in OOP and I may be confused on the concept of accessors in general.

Thanks

**Update:** Today (01/07/2016) I watched video #3 ***Applying MVC*** from the course `Developing iOS 8 Apps with Swift` offered by `Stanford` University in iTunes and in minute **24:15** Paul Hegarty talks about access control, I highly recommend it.

Comment: We do use `private`. We just don't tell you about it, because it's… well… private. 

Comment: Your intuition to use the narrowest possible access control still applies, IMHO. I'm not surprised that the snippets you seen in tutorials give this topic short shrift, as this is an issue that tends to arise in larger practical applications. The only time I consistently see `private` used is when there is some computed property that is backed by some stored property, where direct interaction with that stored property is obviously problematic: You'll often see that marked `private`. But, in short, many of us use `private` in our own code.

Comment: @Rob Would you say that it would be a good practice to make `private` any property that will only be used within the class (class scope) and leave the rest of them as `internal`? This way the code at least will be more readable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Access control in Swift was one of the things that surprised me as well, so you are not alone.  Swift uses a paradigm quite different from that used by C++, Java, C# that I was previously familiar with.

Swift's access control is not based on classes, but on source files and modules.  The idea is that if you write a class, then you should have access to all of its members from another class in the same source file or module by default.  If someone else extends your class, their code will be in a different module and source file, so they won't be able to access your base class members unless you give them access.

If you think about it, Swift paradigm of access control makes as much sense as that of C++/Java, it's just different.

Please see http://www.swiftprogrammer.info/swift_vs_cpp.html for this and other differences between the languages.

Comment: As I understand it is that in theory you only need to use access control if your code will be used in other Xcode projects, correct? I guess we will have a lot of setters and getters since now you have access to all of the properties values (I know, getters and setters belong to computer properties in Swift).

Comment: See my update in my original post for more info on this topic.